# Password protect whole Magento site running on Docker

Tags: magento2, htaccess, docker

I'm still finding my feet both in Magento and Docker. Can anyone suggest how I can password protect a whole Magento site running within Docker?

I understand the best/easiest way to do this is to modify the .htaccess file - but I'm confused as to which one / in which folder.

Thanks in advance!